# Unbuffered query error with Load Data Infile

Tags: php, mysql

I'm following the tutorial here: https://mikaelhoundegnon.wordpress.com/2018/05/02/work-around-of-mysql-load-data-infile-with-on-duplicate-key-update/. A note in case it matters, I'm using Laravel's query builder, but executing raw statements for these particular queries.

My code looks like:

```
$sql = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_part SELECT * FROM part WHERE 1=0";
        $con->statement($sql);

        $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$filePath'
                INTO TABLE temporary_part
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                (field1,field2,field3,field4)";
        $con->statement($sql);
```

I then get the following error:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute. (SQL: LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file.csv' INTO TABLE temporary_part FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' (field1,field2,field3,field4))

There aren't any other open queries outside of what is going on in the provided code. I've confirmed it is the LOAD DATA INFILE query that is throwing the error. Am I doing something incorrectly here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was actually a Laravel facade DB::connection() issue. Apparently with a LOAD DATA INFILE query, it's not good enough to execute raw statements using statement(), but rather has to use DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($sql);